# Getting out from Wireless carrier contract without a penalty

Tags: penalty

I recently got a notification from T-Mobile saying that their agreement ended with my employer and they will no longer provide 15% discount to monthly service charges.

Can I get out of my 2 year contract agreement with T-Mobile ? (still 9 months to go)

Here are my arguments:

1. When I signed up for the contract I expected my charges to be at certain level for the length of my contract. No the prices has increased and I can no longer afford paying increased feed.
2. It is beyond my control that my employer and T-Mobile ended the discount program.

[image: Notice from T-Mobile]

Comment: Depends on your contract.  I would guess not.  Read your contract and if you have any relevant info, post it.

Answer (score 2):

The discount is not part of your contract, its part of the contract between the employer and T-Mobile. As such, it has no bearing on your obligations. When you signed a contract, the price set in it was the price before the discount.